# ByteBuddy: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot attach undefined variable: V

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy, jvm-bytecode

When rebasing the class `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMultimap$Values` from Google Guava, I get an IllegalArgumentException from ByteBuddy.

The inner class is a subclass of `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableCollection` whose method `ImmutableList<E> createAsList()` causes the problem.

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot attach undefined variable: V
at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$Visitor$Substitutor$ForAttachment.onTypeVariable(TypeDescription.java:1973)
at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$Visitor$Substitutor$ForAttachment.onTypeVariable(TypeDescription.java:1896)
at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfTypeVariable$Symbolic.accept(TypeDescription.java:5551)
at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$Visitor$Substitutor.onParameterizedType(TypeDescription.java:1857)
at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$Visitor$Substitutor$ForAttachment.onParameterizedType(TypeDescription.java:1896)
at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfParameterizedType.accept(TypeDescription.java:5017)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.Transformer$ForMethod$TransformedMethod.getReturnType(Transformer.java:377)
at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription$AbstractBase.asTypeToken(MethodDescription.java:685)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodRegistry$Default$Prepared$Entry.resolveBridgeTypes(MethodRegistry.java:916)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodRegistry$Default$Prepared.compile(MethodRegistry.java:778)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForInlining$RedefinitionClassVisitor.visit(TypeWriter.java:3281)
at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForInlining.create(TypeWriter.java:3018)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:1617)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.RebaseDynamicTypeBuilder.make(RebaseDynamicTypeBuilder.java:198)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.make(AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.java:90)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:2566)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase$Delegator.make(DynamicType.java:2668)
at cl.InnerClassLoader.loadClass(InnerClassLoader.java:187)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at test.Stuff.<init>(Stuff.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
at test.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

I've created an example triggering the issue here: https://github.com/erikhakansson/bytebuddytest
The test was modified from an earlier test I had so there might be some garbage in there.

To test, simply run mvn clean install and then run the resulting jar.

Most likely, I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what, so please help! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have found a bug in Byte Buddy. I have resolved this issue (formerly incorrect in release 1.6.14) in Byte Buddy 1.4.17.

Comment: Ah, I see. Anything I can do in the meantime to get around the issue?

Comment: The new version was released yesterday night so I would recommend to just update.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error with the new version. Could it be another issue?

I updated the linked repo to use the new version.

Comment: Are you sure that you updated properly? I had downloaded your project and tested against it.

Comment: I just double checked. Your `main` method returns without errors on a fresh check-out of your project.

Comment: Huh, that's weird. I'll have to check again. I'll do it tonight when I'm by the computer again

Comment: I still get the error, but I realised it's for a different class now:
`com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMultimap$EntryCollection`

I'm running using jdk1.8.0_31 if that matters.

Comment: I updated the test to print out the classname it tries to load, but I suppose that doesn't matter if you can't reproduce it. :/ I'm going to try on a different environment to see if it's something environment specific.

Comment: Hi, I made sure there was no trace of the project and now I can reproduce the error; I will look into it, must have missed something.

Comment: Ah, good to know. Then I'm not going crazy! :) Thanks for all the help!

Comment: No, you are not. Sorry for that. I already identified the core problem and I made a wrong assumption such that my fix made things worse. I have to factor out something before I can fix this problem but I am on it. I will include the fix in 1.4.17.

Comment: The release is out on Maven Central.

Comment: The latest version solved the issue! Thank you! 

(Unrelated: Is there a donation page for bytebuddy?)

Comment: @erikh There is not but this is not necessary. I am a consultant and the way Byte Buddy works for me is that it hopefully generates some business. I appreciate the guesture, though.